# How do I jump to a specific line of code in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Seems like such a simple thing but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you could remove the "4" from the title, it seems to be here to stay.

Comment: Hey yeah good call @Gulzt.  Done.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will do it... This seems to have changed in Xcode 4.

Comment: Works in XCode 8 too.